# Why does <a href='javascript:"text";'> not work?

Tags: javascript, html, url, protocols, standards

The `href` tag can contain "links" of JavaScript protocol. For example:

```
<a href='javascript:alert("Hello World");'>Click</a>
```

Clicking on the link would run the JavaScript code specified within the value of the `href` tag.

We can test this too by typing the value of the `href` tag directly into the browser's URL bar. Try it, type `javascript:alert("Hello World");` into the URL bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

So the code above works as expected. **However**, `javascript:"text"` doesn't work:

```
<a href='javascript:"Hello World";'>Click</a>
```

When I click the link ([*JSFiddler*](http://jsfiddle.net/2pfus0ze/2/); [*G-Host*](https://googledrive.com/host/0B53jM4a9X2fqV0NlWmppWFBwalE/test)), it does *nothing*.

The page content is not replaced with the text `Hello World` **as it would have been** if we had typed `javascript:"Hello World"` directly into the URL bar. Try typing it directly into the URL bar.

Is this a bug?

Why does `href` not work with `"javascript:'text';"`?

Comment: I think if there is any bug in this situation, it would be that `javascript:"Hello World"` causes Hello World to show up in your browser.  In my brief testing, only Internet Explorer does that.  To my knowledge, there is no standard about this behavior, so browsers may be free to do whatever they want.  However executing `"Hello World"` as javascript doesn't put it into the document in *any* browser.  You can verify this using a developer javascript console, even in IE.

Comment: @recursive, Displaying the text "Hello World" is the correct behavior ([test page](https://d152869773ca030e77eeec29e44c90a450b76220.googledrive.com/host/0B53jM4a9X2fqV0NlWmppWFBwalE/test)). There is a standard, see the link in my answer below  *..."Otherwise, the URL must be treated in a manner equivalent to an HTTP resource with a 200 OK response whose Content-Type metadata is text/html and whose response body is the return value converted to a string value."...* [§§](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27649809/632951)

Comment: I am surprised that I never encountered this before.  Unfortunately i still don't have any further insight on your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Somehow or another the code works now,  tested on ([*JSFiddler*](http://goo.gl/9z0GXv); [*G-Host*](https://googledrive.com/host/0B53jM4a9X2fqV0NlWmppWFBwalE/test)):

- Chrome (39.0.2171.95)
- FireFox (33.0.2)
- IE-8 (8.0.6001.18702IC)
- Opera (12.16)

(So [**if** it had been due to  a browser bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27649468/632951), the bug seems to be fixed.)

Still doesn't work on Safari (5.1.7) though.

Comment: Silent downvotes don't help the site. Downvoters may wish to explain how this post can be improved.

Answer (score -1):

Your assumption isn't correct here.

For opening a document with asd written on it, you should open a new window and write the req text "asd" there. Just like:

```
winHandler = window.open("_blank","","");     //Opens a new blank window and is handled by winHandler
winHandler.document.write("asd");    //Writes some text to window opened.
```

So now you can re-write your code in:

1. function and call it. [recommended]
2. Write both Stmt in series.

Another suggestion a `href` expects some url as suggested by others, so use JavaScript event handler `onclick` of invoking or triggering the function. E.g.:

```
<script>
     function openWin(){
         winHandler = window.open("_blank","","");     //Opens a new blank window and is handled by winHandler
         winHandler.document.write("asd");    //Writes some text to window opened.
     }
</script>     
<a href='#' onclick="openWin()">a</a>
```

Comment: but that doesn't explain why typing javascript:"asd" in the url bar works ,does it?

Comment: @Pacierier - garbate in, garbage out. Browsers expect a protocol associated with a URL, e.g. http://. If they don't get the '//' likely they take a guess at what you want and go from there. Try reading the [W3C URL standards](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/) document.