# How should the return value of JavaScript <href> links be handled?

Tags: javascript, html, url, protocols, standards

According to *standards*, what's  the correct way to handle the **return value** of javascript protocol `href` links?

Some examples:

- ```html
  <a href='javascript:"Hello World";'> Click </a> <!-- return a String -->
  ```
- ```html
  <a href='javascript:ThisFunctionReturnsString();'> Click </a>
  ```
- ```html
  <a href='javascript:12345;'> Click </a> <!-- Number -->
  ```
- ```html
  <a href='javascript:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];'> Click </a> <!-- Array -->
  ```
- ```html
  <a href='null;'> Click </a> <!-- null-->
  ```
- ```html
  <a href='undefined;'> Click </a> <!-- undefined-->
  ```
- ```html
  <a href='javascript:{};'> Click </a> <!-- Object -->
  ```

How should a ***standard***-compliant browser handle the return values?

How do current browsers in the wild differ from this standard behavior?

Answer (score 2):

From [Web Applications API §6.1.5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/webappapis.html#javascript-protocol):

The following explains why clicking the links replaces the document content:

> If the result of executing the script is void (there is no return
>   value), then the URL must be treated in a manner equivalent to an HTTP
>   resource with an HTTP 204 No Content response.
>
> **Otherwise, the URL must be treated in a manner equivalent to an HTTP
>   resource with a 200 OK response whose Content-Type metadata is
>   text/html and whose response body is the return value converted to a
>   string value**.

This behavior can also be demonstrated easily by simply pasting `javascript:"Hello World";` in the address bar. Same goes for `javascript:(function() { return "Hello World";})()`.

And the following explains why only your 1 and 2 code snippets are actually doing something.

> Let the script source be the **string** obtained using the content retrieval operation defined for javascript: URLs

Comment: Do you mind elaborting on what does "content retrieval operation" mean? Because, if "response body is the return value converted to a string value", why doesn't the number 12345 be converted to a string value "12345" and displayed as such?

Comment: I did ask myself the same question and concluded that perhaps `Let the script source be the **string** obtained` may explain this. But I have to admit it is very unclear and `content retrieval operation` is also undocumented.